# Application of CPT invariance : some trivial algebra

Tags: homework-and-exercises, particle-physics, cpt-symmetry

I am having some problem in understanding one step in the following algebra.

Consider an interaction where initial state is defined as $ \left|i\right>  $ and final state by $ \left|f\right> $. Now, 
$$ \left|i\right> = \mathcal{ CPT}\left | \bar{i}\right> $$ 
$$ \left|f\right> = \mathcal{ CPT} \left| \bar{f}\right> $$
Using the CPT invariance condition, 
$ \left(\mathcal{ CPT} \right)T \left(\mathcal{ CPT}\right)^{-1}= T^{\dagger}$, 
where $T$ is the transition matrix;
$$ \left<f|T^{\dagger}|i\right> = \left<\bar{f}|T|\bar{i}\right>^{*}$$

Please show explicitly how to derive the last equation.

Comment: Isn't the invariance condition for $T$ that $(\mathcal{CPT})T\left(\mathcal{T^{-1}P^{-1}C^{-1}}\right) = T^\dagger$?

Comment: @rob This condition says, that Transition matrix is invariant under $ \mathcal{CPT} $.

Comment: Well if $$ \left(\mathcal{ CPT} \right)T \left(\mathcal{ CPT}^{-1}\right)= T^{\dagger}$$ Then the converse $$\left(\mathcal{ CPT} \right)T^{\dagger} \left(\mathcal{ CPT}^{-1}\right)= T$$ is true too right?

Comment: What I am asking is, how to get to the last step.

Comment: @seeking_infinity Your edit is better. Inverse of a product of operators is the product of the inverses in the reverse order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So let's start from the relations you gave and transform one of them from ket to bra.
$$ \left|i\right> = \mathcal{ CPT}\left | \bar{i}\right> $$ 
$$ \left<f\right| = \left< \bar{f}\right| (\mathcal{ CPT})^{\dagger} $$
Using the CPT invariance condition, 
$ \left(\mathcal{ CPT} \right)T \left(\mathcal{ CPT}\right)^{-1}= T^{\dagger}$,

It is easy to show that:
$$ \left<f|T^{\dagger}|i\right> = \left<\bar{f}|(\mathcal{CPT})^{\dagger}(\mathcal{ CPT})T|\bar{i}\right> 
$$

Then by the anti-linearity of $\mathcal{CPT}$, 
$\left<\bar{f}|(\mathcal{CPT})^{\dagger}(\mathcal{ CPT})T|\bar{i}\right> = \left<\bar{f}|(\mathcal{CPT})(\mathcal{ CPT})T|\bar{i}\right>^* $

Since $\mathcal{CPT}^2$ = $\mathcal{I}$

$\left<\bar{f}|(\mathcal{CPT})(\mathcal{ CPT})T|\bar{i}\right>^* = \left<\bar{f}|T|\bar{i}\right>^* $

They key step is the anti-linearity condition.